# Reasoning check on geometric distribution question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification, probability-distributions

Consider a biased coin with probability $p$ to show head. Then you toss it twice and consider the result $(H,T)$ as a "head" and the outcome $(T,H)$ as a "tail". If it does not occur neither "head" or "tail", you toss it twice again until you get a "head" or a "tail".

(a) Prove that this experiment corresponds to the unbiased version of the game of "tossing a coin until get head (or tail).

(b) Exhibit the probability mass function and the expectation of the number of tosses necessary to end the experiment.

**MY ATTEMPT**

(a) Based on the independence of the tosses, we have 
$$\textbf{P}(\{(H,T)\}) = p(1-p) = (1-p)p = \textbf{P}(\{(T,H)\})$$

(b) As far as I have noticed, such random variable has a geometric distribution:

$$X\sim G(p(1-p)) \Rightarrow f_{X}(x) = q(1-q)^{x-1}\,\,\text{for}\,\,x\geq 1$$

where $q = p(1-p)$. Thence we conclude that $\textbf{E}(X) = [p(1-p)]^{-1}$.

Am I reasoning correctly? I'd like to hear somebody else's opinion on the subject. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part:

It is geometric distribution with $p_1 = 2p(1-p)$ and $q_1 = p^2+(1-p)^2$ and is $Ge(p_1)$

Thus $P(X=x) = q_1^{x-1}p_1$, $x \ge 1$ where X is the number of trials(double tosses)

And the expectation is $E(\text{No of tosses}(2X)) = \frac{2}{p_1}$